# Show SQL in deployed play application

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've deployed my play application using **play dist** onto my server, but I want to display the application's SQL statements as it runs.

How can I do this?

I've tried adding the following to my application.conf, but has no effect:

```
logger.com.jolbox.bonecp=DEBUG
logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG
```

I've even tried launching the application using **-d**, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to:

1. Remove all logger.* lines from `conf/application.conf`.
2. Create a separate `application-logger.xml` file in the `conf` directory.

This application-logger.xml file should contain the following:

```
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

try (in application.conf)

```
db.default.logStatements=true
```

(or whatever your DataSource name is in place of 'default'.)